# provide password while unzipping a .zip file

Tags: powershell, zip, password-protection

I have a zip file that asks for password while extracting. How to provide this password while extracting it in powershell script?

I have been looking into the Expand-Archive, but it does not show how to insert this password. I have already have the password encrypted in a text file:

```
"P@ssword1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\Temp 2\Password.txt"
```

How to feed the password from the file to the Expand-Archive command ? or what other options are there ?

Comment: from what i can tell, the `Expand-Archive` cmdlet does not support dealing with password protected archives. you will have to use another util - perhaps the command line version of 7zip?

Answer (score 6):

As per the built-in help files and the online PowerShell documentation, the Expand-Archive cmdlet provides no means for this use case, nor does it have an option to add a password.

All cmdlets that do provide such a mechanism, have a '-Credential' switch.

```
# Find all cmdlets / functions with a target parameter
Get-Command -CommandType Function | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'credential'} | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available functions which has a specific parameter'

Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Where-Object { $_.parameters.keys -match 'credential'} | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Results for cmdlets which has a specific parameter'
```

Even the native .Net namespace, '[System.IO.Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files)' does not provide it. Though there is a project that has been around for a long while to do this with .Net.

[About DotNetZip - DotNetZip Documentation](https://documentation.help/DotNetZip/About.htm)

Old project
[DotNetZip - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/181291/dotnetzip)

Forked version
[NuGet Gallery | DotNetZip 1.13.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip)

Yet, this is not PowerShell specific. It's just a standalone '.exe' to use, just like 7zip, WinZip, etc. Yet, if you are willing to dig at the source code and turn it into a module to use, that's a decision for you to make.

Point of note:

There are already modules in the MS powershellgallery.com that have already done this.

```
Find-Package -Name '*DotNetZip*'

Name                           Version          Source           Summary                                                                                            
----                           -------          ------           -------                                                                                            
DotNetZip                      1.13.5           nuget.org        A library for dealing with zip, bzip and zlib from .Net                                            
DotNetZip.Reduced              1.9.1.8          nuget.org        DotNetZip is an easy-to-use, FAST, FREE class library and toolset for manipulating zip files or ...
XAct.IO.Compression.DotNetZip  1.1.17040.3290   nuget.org        An XActLib assembly: a library to work with the essentials of DotNetZip.                           
VirtualPath.DotNetZip          0.3.9            nuget.org        DotNetZip library wrapper for VirtualPath                                                          
DotNetZip.NetStandard          1.12.0           nuget.org        A library for dealing with zip, bzip and zlib from .Net                                            
DotNetZip.Zlib.vNextUnofficial 1.9.8.3          nuget.org        DotNetZip vNext port                                                                               
DotNetZip.Zip.vNextUnofficial  1.9.8.3          nuget.org        DotNetZip vNext port                                                                               
DotNetZip.Android              1.13.5           nuget.org        A library for dealing with zip, bzip and zlib from .Net                                            
DotNetZip.iOS                  1.13.5           nuget.org        A library for dealing with zip, bzip and zlib from .Net                                            
Bardock.Utils.Web.Mvc.DotNe... 1.0.0            nuget.org        MVC and DotNetZip utilities
...
RI.Framework.Extensions.Dot... 0.7.0            nuget.org        Decoupling & Utilities Framework                                                                   
DotNetZipforWindows8.1         1.0.0            nuget.org        i make same changes to make this is a package for zip file with password for windows 8.1 and win...
```

So, use the modules above or you need to shell out to a 3rdP tool, like 7zip, etc...

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a D:\Temp\mytest.zip D:\Temp\mytest.txt -pSecret

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 64 bytes (1 KiB)

Creating archive: D:\Temp\mytest.zip

Add new data to archive: 1 file, 64 bytes (1 KiB)


Files read from disk: 1
Archive size: 230 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok

C:\>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x D:\Temp\mytest.zip D:\Temp\mytest.txt -pSecret

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 230 bytes (1 KiB)

Extracting archive: D:\Temp\mytest.zip
--
Path = D:\Temp\mytest.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 230


No files to process
Everything is Ok

Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 230
```

There are several articles regarding how to properly leverage external cmds with PowerShell.

> [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
>
> [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)
>
> [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)
>
> [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command-line tools (and their
>   weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)
>
> [Execution of external commands in PowerShell done right](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right)
>
> https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/execution-of-external-commands-native-applications-in-powershell-done-right-part-2
>
> https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/04/05/execution-of-external-commands-native-applications-in-powershell-done-right-part-3

Quoting is also important when doing this

> [Quoating specifics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules%20https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/20/powershell-quoting)

So, you'd end up with this ...

```
# Using the call operator
& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' a 'D:\Temp\mytest.zip' 'D:\Temp\mytest.txt' -pSecret
& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' x 'D:\Temp\mytest.zip' 'D:\Temp\mytest.txt' -pSecret
```

Or using Start-Process with that same string.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a module called "7Zip4Powershell" and provided the following command to extract a password protected .zip file.

```
Expand-7Zip -ArchiveFileName "$($downloadedPath)\$($library.Name)" -TargetPath $extractedPath -SecurePassword (Get-Content $unpackingPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString)
```